# Nested(object in object) Filter Search on Object placed in Mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, mongotemplate

[image: Object of Class ConnectedPartners]

This is the Object of CcStorePartnerclass, There is an another Object of Partner class inside this class.

Here i want to make filter on attributes of CcStorePartner obj and attributes of Partner Class,

This is the web service body tag. where i have decleared the filter on the objects which are placed in Mongodb. I'm using MongoTemplate

```
{
    "target":"stores",
    "filter":
    [
        { 
            "storeId" : "a487c" , 
            "Type": "contains"
        },
        {
            "partner.partnerCode": "ucb",
            "Type":"contains"
        }
    ]
}
```

What will be the mongo query. which will provide the List
Here m using this..

`query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("storeId").regex(".*a487c.*","i"));`
`query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("partner.partnerCode").regex(".*ucb.*","i"));`

I'm receiving this error

[image: Error]

Pojo Class
[image: Pojo Class]

and this is the Mongo Template Code which m using- Dynamic Query.
[image: Mongo Template Calling Code]

Comment: There is some inconsistency between the code you posted and error. You've received the error because you queried DBRef partner on name or partnercode but you can only query associations on their id. You should change dbref to embedded document to be able to query on partner fields.

Comment: what to write will you please tell, 
Although I'm not able to search on unique id which is auto generated in CcStorePartner Documnet in mongodb

Comment: You should be able to search on unique id. How are you searching ?

Comment: Payload:- 
{
 "target":"stores",
 "filter":
  [
   { "id" : "3449a488d" , "Type":"contains"}
 
  ]
 }


 query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").regex(".*3449a488d*","i"));

Comment: So this does not work and you get error of some sort ? just to confirm you have ids stored as string correct ?

Comment: it is auto generated. look like this-     "_id" : ObjectId("58d0cf2dce50ac3820c323bb"),

Comment: You have to store id's as string to perform regex search. You have currently stored the id's as objectId type.